# How to use parameter in function with pagination CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have function which takes state name as a parameter and displays all the cities of that specific state. Since list of cities is very long I have used pagination in the same function but when I click on the 'Next' or any other pagination link the function accepts the offset value in the $state variable. The function is

```
public function load_Page($state){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $a = 1;

    $this->db->select("*")->where("userstate" , $a)->where("state" , $state);
    $query0 = $this->db->get("city");

            $this->db->select("*")->where("userstate" , $a)->where("state" , $state);
            $query1 = $this->db->get('city' , 10 , $this->uri->segment(3));
            $config["base_url"] = base_url()."index.php/city/load_Page";
            $total_row = $query0->num_rows();
            $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
            $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
            $config["per_page"] = 10;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);


            $data["state"] = $state;
            $data["result"] = $query1->result();
            //$data["rows"] = $query1->num_rows();
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('city', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

}
```

Is there any other way out to do it or I am going completely wrong?

Comment: Just a tip: I would autoload the database library in config/autoload.php so you don't have to use `$this->load->database();` all the time

Comment: Post your `view` file. Why are you using a transaction to get a result of the single query?

Comment: I am still in my learning curve in CodeIgniter. In my view, I just have a for loop displaying the list of cities of a specific state in a table. The view is very long sorry I can't paste that here. Also please ignore the transaction part as I was learning about it so I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you are paginating, the page number has to come from the URL, and that's always available as a parameter in the controller method. It should default to page 1.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class City extends CI_Controller {

    public function load_page( $state, $page = 1 ){

        // I'm going to use an alias for this model
        $this->load->model('example_model', 'model');

        // Use the URL helper for site_url()
        $this->load->helper('url');

        // Set pagination config
        $config['pagination_settings'] = [
            'per_page'          => 10,
            'use_page_numbers'  => TRUE,
            'uri_segment'       => 4, // This is very important!!!
            'base_url'          => site_url('city/load_page/' . $state)
        ];

        // Get the total rows
        $config['pagination_settings']["total_rows"] = $this->model->pagination_count( $state );

        // Load and initialize pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config['pagination_settings']);

        $data = [
            'state' => $state,
            'rows' => $this->model->get_cities( $state, $page, $config['pagination_settings']['per_page'] ),
            'links' => $this->pagination->create_links()
        ];

        // Use data in views or wherever needed ...
        $this->load->view('city', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Create the rows to paginate
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        // I'm going to use an alias for this model
        $this->load->model('example_model', 'model');

        $this->model->setup();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Next, you should move your database queries to a model. You don't need to use transactions for your 2 select type queries.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function pagination_count( $state )
    {
        return $this->db->where("state" , $state)
            ->count_all_results('city');
    }

    public function get_cities( $state, $page, $limit )
    {
        $offset = ( $page * $limit ) - $limit;

        $query = $this->db->where("state" , $state)
            ->limit( $limit, $offset )
            ->get('city');

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            return $query->result();

        return NULL;
    }

    /**
     * Setup for testing
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->load->dbforge();

        $fields = array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 5,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'state' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '32',
            ),
            'city' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '32',
            ),
        );
        $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('city', TRUE);

        for( $x = 1; $x <= 40; $x++ )
        {
            $this->db->insert('city', array(
                'state' => 'ca',
                'city'  => 'x' . $x
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view that I used:

```
<?php

echo '<h1>' . $state . '</h1>';

echo $links . '<br /><br />';

foreach( $rows as $row )
{
    echo $row->city . '<br />';
}
```

To set up the database for testing, I went to:

```
http://localhost/index.php/city/setup
```

Then to check out that the pagination works, I went to:

```
http://localhost/index.php/city/load_page/ca
```

It should work for you, as this code is now fully tested.

UPDATE --------------------

If you want to add more parameters to your pagination, do it with query strings. You will need to set the pagination config with this extra setting:

```
$config['pagination_settings']['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

That means the config would look like this:

```
$config['pagination_settings'] = [
    'per_page'           => 10,
    'use_page_numbers'   => TRUE,
    'uri_segment'        => 4, // This is very important!!!
    'base_url'           => site_url('city/load_page/' . $state),
    'reuse_query_string' => TRUE
];
```

And then you create the link to the first page with your params:

```
http://localhost/index.php/city/load_page/ca?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

And because of the `reuse_query_strings` being set to `TRUE`, that means that `?a=1&b=2&c=3` would all be attached to the pagination links.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but it didn't solve my problem. My problem is that when I click on 2 or 3 or Next of pagination numbers the above controller function re-runs without any value in the argument $state which leads to an error as I require the state to show cities specific to it.

Comment: My code passes $state to the pagination config's base_url, where your code does not. That's how $state will persist. Maybe something is going on that has nothing to do with pagination, but with $state itself?

Comment: I've revised my answer and now included all of my code when testing, complete with view and database setup. It works 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also could you please suggest me a way out if I have more than one parameter. The above solution doesn't work for n number parameters.

Comment: CodeIgniter pagination does allow you to tack on a query string and maintain the query string throughout your paging links. See the user guide for more info. With what I've provided, it should be fun for you to figure out.

Comment: I am having a really hard time figuring it. Please, Brian help me out.

Comment: I revised by answer to explain. See answer below UPDATE ------

Comment: Thanks bro you are really helpful

Comment: Glad to help. Before CI3 we didn't have the reuse_query_string setting, and we had to do it manually. This  is SO much easier.

Comment: Best Answer :) Really Helpful.